# How to pass an argument in href?

Tags: python, html, href, tornado

I want to pass the query string value in href as an argument while I render the page.I tried:
`<a href="/room?nw=" + nw ><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Add</button></a>`

I use a tornado framework and the python script is:

```
class Room(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        nw=Test
        self.render("Room.html",nw=nw)
```

But the query string does not take the value "Test" it gives "/room?nw=" as the URL.i.e. without the value Test.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with {{}},

```
<a href="/room?nw={{nw}}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Add</button></a>
```

http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/templates.html